# Is there a Greek word meaning to purr?

Tags: vocabulary, greek, animals

I've heard that there is no known verb for purring (of a cat) in Greek.  Is that true?  Any qualified guess as to what verb a Greek might have used?

Comment: Modern Greek has γουργουρίζω "to purr; to gurgle", but I am not aware of a Classical Greek word.

Answer (score 10):

Indeed, I cannot find any hits for "purr" in the LSJ, nor any verbs containing the words "cat" or "cats" in their entries! Quite a shame.

But there are several onomatopoeic verbs for making a low growling sound, such as ἀρῥάζω (*arrházō*), "to go *arrha*". *Arrha*, with a long, extended trill, sounds fairly close to a purr.

For a usage example, here's Aelian:

> τὸ μὲν γὰρ βρυχᾶται, μυκᾶται δὲ ἄλλο, καὶ χρεμέτισμα ἄλλου καὶ ὄγκησις [ἄλλου], ἄλλου βληχηθμός τε καὶ μηκασμός, καί τισι μὲν ὠρυγμός, τισὶ δὲ ὑλαγμὸς φίλον, καὶ ἄλλῳ ἀρράζειν.
>
> So one type of animal roars, another bellows, some make whinnying sounds, others make braying sounds, others go *bleh* and *meh*, some like howling, some like barking, and still others like to go *arrha*.

(*DNA* V.51, translation mine.)

This is the sort of thing you just don't get in modern biology textbooks.

Comment: +1 for the punchline